# Menu button wont move vertically

Tags: html, css, menu

I’m trying to make a menu open button for my website, but there’s one slight problem, when I try to assign it to move vertically, for example do `margin-top: 100px` it won’t move. But when I set a `margin-left` it changes position and moves horizontally! I have no idea as to why this is happening. I would love to get some advice on how to put the menu button a bit further downwards. I have a feeling it has something to do with the attribute being a `span`, but I have no idea. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap");
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
      font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-size: cover;
}
#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}
.navMenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.navMenu a {
    color: #f6f4e6;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.navMenu a:hover {
    color: #fddb3a;
}
.navMenu .dot {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fddb3a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
    transform: translateX(30px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(1):hover~.dot {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(80px);
    transform: translateX(80px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(2):hover~.dot {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(240px);
    transform: translateX(240px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(3):hover~.dot {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(400px);
    transform: translateX(400px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navMenu a:nth-child(4):hover~.dot {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(570px);
    transform: translateX(570px);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 120px;
}
.openNav {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    color: black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1305px) {
    .dot {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .overlay a {
        font-size: 20px
    }
    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>City</title>
        <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <nav class="navMenu">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <a href="#">Blog</a>
                    <a href="#">Work</a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <div class="dot"></div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="openNav" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a feeling it has something to do with the attribute being a `span`

That is right, because the `span` is by default has `display: inline`, and if you change it to `display: block` and apply some `margin-top: 100px` you see it changes the position.

```css
.openNav{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```